# Removing Unwanted Author From Author Dropdown in TFS (Version 15.105.25716.0)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to remove some authors from the authors drop-down in TFS. 
These authors do not have any commit in their name. And few entries are not valid authors. Can we do that on TFS? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this could not be achieved for now.

This filter is deigned for [history result filtering.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/commit-history?view=vsts#history-result-filtering) You can filter commits by authors. You will see authors of most recent commits in the author filter drop down. In case you are not able to find an author in the drop down, then you can type the author name or email address and search for all commits by that author.

[image]

It's just not able to manually manage the droplist of Author such as sorting order, **delete** and so on. If you really need this feature, suggest you submit a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.